# Tableau - AWS connection to Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, tableau-api

I got my Tableau connected to a MySQL database hosted on AWS.
All working great, but every time I / someone opens a dashboard, they are asked to log into the database. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because they didn't save the data source with credentials embedded

Comment: Hey grobins. I think you are right! It would make sense. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I think I found it - http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/embedding-database-credentials-tableau-server?lang=es-es